# Django/South set up fails on python manage.py schemamigration testapp --initial

Tags: python, django, django-south

I am trying to setup south for the first time on my dev environment. I have several models already setup before. Once South install is complete, I followed the documentation for south to convert my existing app.

However, I am getting the below traceback. Any ideas?

Thank You.

```
./manage.py convert_to_south testapp
Creating __init__.py in '/home/testapp/../testapp/migrations'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 14, in <module>
execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.6.egg/south/management/commands/convert_to_south.py", line 70, in handle
management.call_command("schemamigration", app, initial=True, verbosity=verbosity)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 166, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.6.egg/south/management/commands/schemamigration.py", line 140, in handle
    for action_name, params in change_source.get_changes():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.6.egg/south/creator/changes.py", line 444, in get_changes
    model_defs = freeze_apps([self.migrations.app_label()])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.6.egg/south/creator/freezer.py", line 35, in freeze_apps
    model_defs[model_key(model)] = prep_for_freeze(model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.6.egg/south/creator/freezer.py", line 71, in prep_for_freeze
    fields = modelsinspector.get_model_fields(model, m2m=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.6.egg/south/modelsinspector.py", line 411, in get_model_fields
args, kwargs = introspector(field)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.6.egg/south/modelsinspector.py", line 371, in introspector
    kwargs[kwd] = get_value(field, defn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.6.egg/south/modelsinspector.py", line 268, in get_value
    if "default" in options and value == options['default']:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 124, in __cmp__
    return cmp(self.creation_counter, other.creation_counter)
AttributeError: class NOT_PROVIDED has no attribute 'creation_counter'
```

Here is my model code.

I had atleast twenty tables that were already working with syncdb. I just wanted to convert to south because dropping tables and recreating  is a hassle. I have removed most of the model code to troubleshoot and this is what is left. Even then I get the same exact traceback.

```
import datetime
import urllib

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.admin.util import quote
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.db import connection, transaction
"""
class BaseTable(models.Model):
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('updated'), auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)   

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
"""

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # Other fields here
    accepted_eula = models.BooleanField()
    favorite_animal = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Dragons")
```

Comment: accidentally clicked update

Comment: Maybe something wrong in the model. Can you post the code?

Comment: I had atleast twenty tables that were already working with syncdb. I just wanted to convert to south because dropping tables and recreating  is a hassle. I have removed most of the model code to troubleshoot and this is what is left. Even then I get the same exact traceback. I have updated the original question with the model code, since the comment doesnt allow long posts.

Comment: Did you try schemamigration --init and then migrate --fake?

Comment: Yes. --initial gives me the same error. --fake doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have South use start tracking pre-existing tables, you have to run a syncdb right after you install it.  In other words, you should follow these steps:

```
$ pip install south
$ nano settings.py
Add south to installed apps & save
$ python manage.py syncdb
$ python manage.py convert_to_south <app>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but these are the exact instructions I followed and I get the above errors.